# Disable style on a specific web page

Tags: php, wordpress, css-selectors

I am using a wordpress theme and I would like to disable a form on the home page of the website. I do not have any skill in web design.

The form is defined by a dynamic-style.php file and **setting the border to 0px solve the problem**. I do understand that those settings apply to every page. Adding a condition in this file seems like a bad idea.

**How can I apply this settings only to a specific page ?**

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually the home page in wordpress has the class `home` in its `body` tag, so it should work to add this CSS rule:

```
.home form {
  display: none;
}
```

This disables the display of all forms on that page. If there are several forms on that page, you should put the class name or the ID of that form into that selector instead of the form tag, like

```
.home .newsletter_application {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That's funny cause .home didn't work. I had to put that css code : `body.page-id-1106 #main { ... }`.

Answer (score 1):

Generally in wordpress each page/post have a unique ID, so if you inspect the **body** element you will find in the class something like this **page-id** or anything else that should be unique.

So you can apply your CSS using this unique class.